# Change keyboard's text pad with number pad

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button, android-keypad

I have EditText and input type is textNoSuggestions.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/firstName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Name"
                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Also i have one button and in button onclick method i try to change keyboard's input type.This is a source

```
 final Button changeKeyboard = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.change_keyboard);
    changeKeyboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            firsName.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        }
    });
```

Is it a possible to change keyboards' input type in button click when keyboard is showing?
How i can solve my problem thanks everyone

Comment: This seems like a unique problem, and after searching SO, I couldn't find a similar question. Good luck with finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

set is setTransformationMethod(), not setInputType(). So something like:

```
firstName.setTransformationMethod(numberTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Maybe you did not understand my question.I want to change keyboard's  text pad with number pad in button click (when keyboard is showing) @jai khambhayta

Answer (score 0):

On your code, change:

```
firsName.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

to this (firstName with "t", the name on your xml):

```
firstName.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Also, you positively can change your keyboard calling `setInputType`, like this: **firstName.setInputType(x)**, where **x** is an int and can be 1 (alfanumeric); 2 (numeric) or 3 (phone like).

EDIT:

You can hide your keyboard calling this on your activity:

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: It's most likely not that :) That's a typo in naming a variable, it would cause a compile-time error if it were that. Or a NullPointer if the id was not good.

Comment: It's working only when keyboard is hide @statosdotcom

Comment: So hide, change it, and raise again.

Answer (score 0):

```
firsName.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```